# Android EditText Action To Apply Filters

Tags: android

```
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView3);
    // Array holding our data
    String[] allproduct = {"TV", "Mobile", "Laptop", "KichenWare", "Apple Iphone", "Samsung S6"};
    //adapter which will convert each data item into view item.
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.allproductslist, R.id.textView12, allproduct);
    //place each view-item inside listview by setting adapter for our listview
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    // Register the ListView  for Context menu
    registerForContextMenu(listview);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Select The Action");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Edit");//groupId, itemId, order, title
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Remove");
}
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    if(item.getTitle()=="Edit"){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Data Available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if(item.getTitle()=="Remove"){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Access", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

 1.
```

1. This is my activity 
        2. Here When the user select any one of the product it will popup "edit" and "Remove" actions.
        3. When the edit button is selected It'll display "no data available".
        4. But my requirement is It should redirect to Another screen that is allowed to apply filters(edit user choice page)
        5. Here i'm including what I have done up to now.
        6. Any help appreciated thankful to them.

   ```
   . If the user selects any check box and save the choice.
   ```

   2. I'm Trying to develop an app.
   3. I'm very new to android.
   4. You will find my layout files also.
   5. Can any Help me.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:scrollIndicators="top|bottom"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            android:layout_gravity="top">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="You Are Looking For..."
                        android:id="@+id/textView10"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:textSize="30dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="338dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/editText"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:autoText="true"
                        android:paddingTop="20dp"
                        android:hint="Product" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="500dp"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2.05">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Filters"
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:baselineAligned="false">

                        <ListView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:id="@+id/listView"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />

                        <ListView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:id="@+id/lv5"
                            android:layout_weight="0.7" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Apply"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:background="#88b9f8"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

1. This is my Layout XML.
2. This is the page I want to redirect  when the edit action is selected.

---

Comment: Edit the question.. just post the code where you are struck. the question now is too broad and difficult to understand

Comment: ya sure I removed some stuff @Dhina

Comment: Whats the issue now you dont want the toast but anther activity should be called?

Comment: My Question is if edit action is selected Then it should redirect to productprofile.xml layout.

Comment: You need to have an activity which setcontentview  productprofile.xml

Comment: And use intent to go to that activity in place of Toast.

Comment: Exactly i don't want to toast@Dhina

Comment: Remove toast and add intent there.

Comment: Can you provide some example or any code@Dhina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    if(item.getTitle()=="Edit"){
         Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivityName.this,ActivityYouWantToCall.class);
         startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if(item.getTitle()=="Remove"){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Access", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot boss@Dhina

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="AutoCompleteTextView" >

    <requestFocus />
</AutoCompleteTextView>
```